# Redux Observable, React, componentDidMount fetch from API cannot get properties from objects

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

```
import { fetchPosts  } from '../actions';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {bindActionCreators, dispatch} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes  from 'prop-types';
import map from 'lodash/fp/map';
import flatten from 'lodash/fp/flatten';
import sortBy from 'lodash/fp/sortBy';
import compose from 'lodash/fp/compose';
import take from 'lodash/fp/take';
import _ from 'lodash';


class PostsIndex extends Component {

state = {
    posts: []
};

    componentDidMount() {

        this.props.fetchPosts();


    }

    displayPosts () {
        //console.log(post) works, console.log(post.title) returns undefined.
        return  _.map(this.props.posts, (post)=>{debugger;console.log(post.title);});
    }

    render() {
        if(this.props.posts.length === 0) {
            return (<div>Loading...</div>);
        }
        return (<ul>{this.displayPosts()}</ul>);
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        posts: (state.posts) ? state.posts : []
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
    return  bindActionCreators({fetchPosts: fetchPosts}, dispatch);
   }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PostsIndex);
```

I can do console.log(post) in

```
    displayPosts () {
        //console.log(post) works, console.log(post.title) returns undefined.
        return  _.map(this.props.posts, (post)=>{debugger;console.log(post.title);});
    }
```

But if I try console.log(post.title) I get undefined.

Likewise if I try to do something like:

```
    displayPosts () {
        //console.log(post) works, console.log(post.title) returns undefined.
        return  _.map(this.props.posts, (post)=>{return <div>post.title</div>;});
    }
```

I get nothing back.

Down here you can see the result of console.log().
The former comes from the epic the latter one from the component.

[image: Console logs]

Here there's a link to the repo that I did open:
https://github.com/Deviad/redux-router-playground

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is actually in your reducer (found from your linked repo):

```
export default function postsReducer(state=[], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.FETCH_POSTS_FULLFILLED:
            // THIS IS THE PROBLEM:
            return [
                ...state,
                action.payload
            ];

        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

`action.payload` is already an array, but you place it inside another array, so an array of arrays. So when you map over `this.props.posts` you only get 1 result, the actual array of posts. When you were logging, you probably just didn't notice.

```
// THIS IS THE PROBLEM:
return [
    ...state,
    action.payload
];
```

Instead, you *could* just return the array as-is:

```
return action.payload;
```

---

While the above solution is IMO acceptable (and let's be honest, shipping code is #1 priority), this actually is still not the most idiomatic way to use redux. Instead, think of redux as a database. How would you store (aka normalize) these in a database? If you answered "indexed by ID" you're right!

So your redux state might look something like this:

```
{
    posts: {
        '123': {
            id: '123',
            title: 'first title'
        },
        '456': {
            id: '456',
            title: 'second title'
        }
    }
}
```

Here's one way you might do that:

```
export default function postsReducer(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.FETCH_POSTS_FULLFILLED:
            return action.payload.reduce((acc, post) => {
                acc[post.id] = post;
                return acc;
            }, { ...state });
            // use Object.assign if object-spread
            // syntax isn't supported

        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Because variations of this is common, many times nested, some will choose to use the normalizr library instead:

```
import { normalize, schema } from 'normalizr';

const postSchema = new schema.Entity('posts');

export default function postsReducer(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.FETCH_POSTS_FULLFILLED:
            // use Object.assign if object-spread
            // syntax isn't supported
            return {
                ...state,
                ...normalize(action.payload, [postSchema]).entities.posts
            };
// etc
```

Since in your case you need them back as an array of posts in that UI container, it also has utilities for denormalizing as well, or you can do it with `Object.values` if supported:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        posts: Object.values(state.posts)
    };
}
```

The `normalize()` call also returns an array of the IDs you might find useful to store in redux somewhere, or you could just use `Object.keys(state.posts)` on-demand when you need it--this is what I do because it prevents synchronization issues, but it's not always practical for perf reasons if the number of items is massive. That's an issue I would worry about when it happens.

You may be wondering why on earth we would go to that trouble if we're just going to denormalize it again; the full answer is long winded, but the short gist is consistency, ease of future state updates, and quick "post by ID" lookup for later views. This is a major part of what makes redux great, otherwise it becomes mostly a time-travelling glorified getter/setter, which is not nearly as worth the boilerplate.

This is discussed in the [Normalizing State Shape](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html) section of the redux docs.

Comment: @jayhelps thank you. You clarified what was unclear to me and also provided an excellent alternative to using _.mapKeys() from lodash.

Comment: @jayhelps, given my integration to your answer, which one would be the best way to iterate through the iterable structure? I ask this because in some languages, taking into account performance issues, it's better foreach and in some others map. For example in PHP foreach might perform better than map on 5.6. In other languages it's better map.

Comment: It looks like the best option is the first. Performance wise on a small set of data they do the same task in the same time: 7/10 of a second in this case. From a memory consumption point of view the latter with Array.prototype.slice.call() takes 10 more MB already with a small set of data coming in.

Comment: There is also another solution which does not require any copy into a variable:     displayPosts () {
        return  Object.values(this.props.posts).map((post)=>{
            return (<div>{post.title}</div>);
        });
    }

Comment: Hey @DavidePugliese you're very welcome, glad it helped! Followup questions should be made as a new Stack Overflow question.